# Perform long running operations when receiving SMS on API < 21

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm building an app that will listen for incoming SMS messages, perform some potentially long running operations and send back a reply if some conditions are met.

I've got the listening part working using a `BroadcastReceiver`, but I'm not sure how/where to perform the potentially long running operations. The [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) states that

> After onReceive(), the system can kill the process at any time to
>   reclaim memory, and in doing so, it terminates the spawned thread
>   running in the process. To avoid this, you should either call
>   goAsync() (if you want a little more time to process the broadcast in
>   a background thread) or schedule a JobService from the receiver using
>   the JobScheduler, so the system knows that the process continues to
>   perform active work.

And also:

> Calling goAsync() in your receiver's onReceive() method and passing
>   the BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult to a background thread. This keeps
>   the broadcast active after returning from onReceive(). However, even
>   with this approach the system expects you to finish with the broadcast
>   very quickly (under 10 seconds). It does allow you to move work to
>   another thread to avoid glitching the main thread.

Furthermore, `JobScheduler` is not available on API < 21.

So how would I achieve this on API 16 - 20?

Comment: i think JobIntent service is better solution as you target 16-20 because it work from 14 and onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a `Service` in your `BroadcastReceiver` to do the long-running operation and send back the result. You could use an `IntentService` or a regular `Service`.