# broadcast receiver stops automatically after some time

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

In one of my application i need to update user location in background after some period of time 
I created

```
DataSendingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
from that i called a class DataSendingService data = new DataSendingService(context);
```

some of my code is :

```
public class DataSendingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context context;
    GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    MySharedPreferenses mySharedPreferenses;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.context = context;
        mySharedPreferenses = new MySharedPreferenses(context);
        if (!mySharedPreferenses.isUserLogin()) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d("DataSendingReceiver", "receiver excuted");
        DataSendingService data = new DataSendingService(context);
gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(context);
```

And DataSendingService  is a class

```
public class DataSendingService implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
```

and in manifest i added

```
<receiver
            android:name=".receiver.DataSendingReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"

            android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped"
            android:process=":remote" />
```

please help me

Comment: Do you have any scheduling mechanism that fire up the Broadcast receiver?

Comment: Broadcast receiver lives accordingly to its context. Which is the context of DataSendingService?

Comment: You must not perform any operations that are longer that starting an activity or service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407154/perform-long-running-operations-when-receiving-sms-on-api-21

Comment: Broadcast lifecycle is about 10 sec, you need to start a service and perform task into service